The mapview() function does not display the map on the display
Recently, the mapview() function has stopped working correctly. Instead of the card, I get an empty display, while everything worked fine before. In order to solve this problem,  What is the problem if there are no errors or conflicts? And how to solve this problem?
I reinstalled the mapview() package several times and even completely deleted and downloaded different versions of R and Rstudio several times.

This is a known issue with the Viewer Pane in R 4.4.0 with many htmlwidget-based packages. Installing the patched version resolved this for me.

You may want to install Rtools along with R and Rstudio. I run into the same issue. After downloading Rtools, mapview() function showed the interactive map.
